# Wrong status during using waitpid with WHOHANG

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix

I want to know, when my child process is exiting. But I don't want to block my application, so I use WNOHANG.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void handler(int nsig) {
  int status;
  waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG);
  printf("nsig=%i; status=%i\n", nsig, status);
  if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    printf("Exited\n");
  }
}

int main() {  
  struct sigaction act;
  act.sa_handler = handler;
  if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "sigaction failed\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  pid_t fpid;
  fpid = fork();
  if (fpid == 0) {
    execlp("okular", "okular", 0);
  }
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```

It works fine if I close "okular" as usual.

```
$ ./test
nsig=17; status=0
Exited
```

But if I do something like

```
kill -STOP OKULAR_PID
```

I have the same output and that's wrong for me, because okular didn't exit in fact.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but you should be aware that calling `printf` from a signal handler usually results in undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is right, because SIGCHLD is defined as Child terminated or stopped as can be seen in this [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal+7) for signal.  SIGCLD is a synonym for SIGCHLD.

Comment: @Ximik: You should only inspect `status` if `waitpid()` returned a value `> 0`.